# PL/SQL: Executing Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a procedure. It is giving an error ( ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows). As for a specific department_id there are more than one employees.  But how to solve this problem ?

```
Create Procedure PP1
(ID in number, Percent in number, Sal out number, increase_sal out number) IS    
Begin
Select salary, salary *(1+percent/100) into sal, increase_sal    
From employees    
where department_id= id;    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sal || ' ' || increase_sal);    
END;    
/    

Variable a number
Variable b number
Exec PP1 (100, 10, :a, :b)
Print a b
```

Thanks,
Kuntal Roy

Comment: What do you expect your output to be? A variable can only hold one value at a time, so you can't execute a `select...into...` that returns more than one row.

Comment: Yes. If I would have used employee_id =id instead of department_id=id, the procedure would have returned value.
But If I want to increase salary for specific department how to do that ?

Comment: Right, so what do you expect the value of `a` and `b` to be coming out of your procedure when you use `department_id` instead? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I want to display the salary and increased salary for a specific department (say 100) with a increment of 10% in salary. In such case what should be the query ?

Comment: Just execute the query you have directly. You don't need to put it inside of a stored procedure.

Comment: @user2788235 - What would the `sal` and `increase_sal` `OUT` parameters contain if there were multiple employees in the department?  Do you want your `OUT` parameters to be collections?

Comment: Yes. That's the best way to do. But I am learning procedure, so was trying to do this. There must be an way to do this by using procedure (though an unnecessary effort, but just for learning).

Comment: @Justin Cave- Yes. Right you are, If there are multiple employees in the department it has to be collection.

Comment: You need to use cursors in this scenario. Get the result of the query into cursor and then loop through the cursor to print values.

Comment: @Justin Cave. Tried as you said and it worked perfectly.
Thank You

Comment: @GriffeyDog Appreciate your help. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like (untested)

```
CREATE TYPE num_tbl IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

 CREATE PROCEDURE raise_dept_salaries( p_dept_id   IN employees.department_id%type,
                                      p_raise_pct IN NUMBER,
                                      p_old_sals OUT num_tbl,
                                      p_new_sals OUT num_tbl )
 AS
 BEGIN
   SELECT salary
     BULK COLLECT INTO p_old_sals
     FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = p_dept_id;

   UPDATE employees
      SET salary = salary * (1 + p_raise_pct)
    WHERE department_id = p_dept_id
RETURNING salary
     BULK COLLECT INTO p_new_sals;
 END;
```

Now, splitting things up this way does introduce the possibility that some other session will modify the data between your first `SELECT` and your `UPDATE` so this isn't really safe to use in a multi-user environment.  Of course, you really wouldn't want to return both the old and the new salaries in the first place since you already know that they are going to be directly related to each other.  If you only returned the collection of new salaries, then you would only need a single `UPDATE` statement and you wouldn't have the race condition.

Comment: I have done the same but by using a record & cursor.
But your process is much easier